# How do I lazy load or partial download of a json file?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a json file with this structure:

```
myCallback({
    "title": "data",
    "content": "data",
    "images": [
        {
            "img1": "data",
            "img2": "data"
        }
    ]
})
```

I would like to know it it is possible to parse the file and extract for example only the title, before it is completely finished downloading.

json files are stored in a remote server, therefor I use jsonp and later parse the full file, but I would like to skip the images (base64 encoded) and only download the first part / title / content.

Comment: [_"JSONP by nature cannot be streamed."_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6558625/139010)

Comment: Just write some code server-side that gets only the chunks you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know it it is possible to parse the file and extract for example only the title, before it is completely finished downloading.

Because you're using JSONP, **no, this is not possible.** [JSONP by nature cannot be streamed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6558625/139010) It relies on a cooperative server passing well-formed data to your page in a `<script>` tag.

Want less data? You'll have to convince the remote server to give you less.