# How can I stream live data and present it in a line chart using PHP, cURL, ajax

Tags: php, ajax, curl

There is a piece of hardware that records data. I can call an API to get the stream of data via cURL. It records a new row of data every seconds. I would like to stream this data and present it in a line chart over time. With PHP and maybe AJAX. I would like to see a moving chart in the browser refreshing the browser in every seconds or using Ajax. What kind of tools do I need? What is the best way of doing this?

Thank you, Everybody these are really useful things.
At the moment I'm struggling to get the data from the hardware.
I can reach the data via an interface which is written  like this:

```
192.168.150.130:2345/realtime
```

Then I can see in the browser this:

```
DM_NumLogChans=5
DM_NumDataModes=1

DM_LogicalChan=1
DM_ChanType=SEQUENTIAL
DM_NumDims=2
DM_DataMode=1
DM_DataModeType=TIMHIS
DM_AxisLabel.Dim1=Time
DM_AxisLabel.Dim2=Value
DM_AxisUnits.Dim1=secs
DM_AxisUnits.Dim2=microstrain
DM_SampleRate=1.000000
DM_TimeBase=0.0
DM_ChanName=bridge_1
DM_UserMin=-583.220764
DM_UserMax=940.916199


DM_Start=
-439.779    -391.875    -680.114    1001.37 0
-442.068    -396.62 -680.945    1001.37 0
-443.571    -399.705    -680.639    1001.37 0
-445.598    -404.848    -684.662    1001.37 0
```

These are recorded data I can't get it from the URL. I would like to save it or live stream it somehow.

Comment: This answer can be useful to find out how to actually stream data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6558625

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use Google Charts's [Line plot](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#creatingpopulating). See [this jsFiddle example of how to add data automatically](http://jsfiddle.net/F83Mx/1/). This is simple as using the `data.addRow([ DATA_INDEX, VALUE_1, VALUE_2, ... ]);`

This use jQuery for plot initialization and "click" event. You'll have to make a loop in order to retrieve data and add it to the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the various JS chart libraries out there should be able to present a line chart for you via loading data up through ajax calls.  Here are a few:

http://www.fusioncharts.com

http://www.chartjs.org

http://www.jscharts.com

http://www.amcharts.com

... and there are plenty more.  Just find one that works best for you.

To run the ajax call that refreshes the charts every x-seconds, use something like this:

[Call jQuery Ajax Request Each X Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes)

Also, take a look at this answer on the amCharts forum:
http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12625