# How do I stream remote multiple webcams to multiple users

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webcam, wowza, adobe-media-server

I need to capture multiple users' webcams in the browser and then broadcast it to multiple users.  This must include an audio and video stream with low and high quality options. Ideally, I would not like to use flash but having flash as a fallback is totally fine.

When the webcam is broadcast to the users, this must work on as many platforms as possible.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 All I have tried to use is WebRTC and WebcamJS to be honest none of that has worked at all well.

Comment: _"none of that has worked at all well"_ Can you include what you have tried at Question? Which portion did not work? You could create a single `.html` document which included all uploaded video?

Comment: @guest271314 Capturing the webcam is the easy part but sending the feed to a server to rebroadcast it is what I am struggling with.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http/ . Which portion of `webRTC` approach did not return expected result?

Comment: WebRTC gives an easy access to web camera, but as you said, the hard part is to share the streams. There're quite many things to handle, but luckily there are some services that aid with stream sharing. In one of my projects I used a commercial OpenTok service that handles all the dirty details of WebRTC connection layer. They may still have a free one month test period, so give it a try. (And I'm not working in that company :-D)