# local HTML listen to local UDP packets

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, udp

I have created a `C++` application which sends UPD packets to an IP and port. Here, the IP is the local IP of my computer and I like to see the visualized packets in my own way on my browser. I have created an HTML file. However, my knowledge in HTML and Javascript socket programming is low. The following code I wrote does not work. I prefer not to use `nodejs` or 3rd party unless there is no other alternative. How should I fix this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Listen to UDP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var port_number=1414;
var dgram = require("dgram");

var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
    var to_log="server got: " + msg + " from " +
        rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port;
    $("#logs").prepend(to_log);
    console.log(to_log);
});

server.on("listening", function () {
    var address = server.address();
    var to_log="server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port;
    $("#logs").prepend(to_log);
    console.log(to_log);
});

server.bind(port_number);
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#logs" ).prepend( "<div>Listening to port "+port_number+"...</div>" );
});
</script>

<div id="logs">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http/

Comment: @guest271314, How does it handle UDP packets?

Comment: You can create a chrome app https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp

Comment: @guest271314, I am using firefox. I will prefer to keep my code cross-platform.

Comment: You can try using `WebRTC` http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#peer-to-peer-data- , https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245