# Javascript real-time voice streaming and processing it in django backend

Tags: javascript, django, webrtc, audio-streaming, voice-recognition

Hi I'm currently working on a project where I want to stream users' voice, using js, in realtime - from user's perspective, think Google's speech recognition API demo.

So far I tried few jquery libraries but they doesn't seem to work like I expected - there was either no compatibility with web browser, they couldn't detect microphone or sending to server failed.

Recently, I was exploring webrtc and it seems it could do the job, but I'm not sure if it's possbile to stream from web browser to django backend.

I don't want to use neither node.js nor java's apllets.

I will appreciate any help with js as well as with receiving voice stream in django. Thank you!

Comment: See [Method for streaming data from browser to server via HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate parts here to consider: signaling and media.

The signaling part (as well as the application logic) can be handled by django. The media part can't.

In order to handle the media part you will need to use a media server that receives and processes that data - the low level media processing parts are usually implemenetd in C/C++. See http://kurento.org for a media server framework that can fit your needs (though it isn't written in Python).