# tcp socket with javascript

Tags: javascript, tcp

How can I open a tcp connection with javascript, send data and close the connection synchronously?

I am looking for something like this

```
   var connection = new tcpconnectio();
   connection.open(ip, port)
   connection.send(data)
   connection.close
```

But synchronously , any suggestions?

Comment: See [Method for streaming data from browser to server via HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http/37903033?s=1|4.1486#37903033)

Comment: is this node or a browser?

Answer (score 0):

i am new to the forum and going to give this a shot. I dont believe its possible to send data if the port is closed at the same time. You could venture for closing it the second that the data reaches the file size amount.

aka- if the data file is 100kb you could make a 
data = download amount
datamax = 100kb

do {connection.open}
while (data != datamax)

anyways just a thought. ill look up more online and see if i can find something. good luck!