# send live video using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, live-streaming

i need to send a live streaming from pc to pc , both of them using just the web browser (IE, firefox o chrome), exist a library (javascript) that could help me to push the stream from the sender to the media server (ffmpeg-ffserver, wowza, etc).

Comment: A library is not necessary to meet expected result. What issues are you experiencing achieving requirement? Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: a complex question that has many answers depending on what you value as important. Too broad to answer. Please post code related questions (IE why doesn't this code work).

Comment: See [Method for streaming data from browser to server via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to stream a video signal from the webcam. Then the way to go is to use webRTC, but it is still very new (wowza server just started to support it) and it is only supported in some modern browsers. So you will encounter many issues.

Most of the existing solution still use flash to capture from the webcam and encode in rtmp.