# Uploading a stream using fetch client

Tags: javascript, aurelia, fetch-api

In an aurelia project I'm trying to upload a large file using fetch.
I can do an upload of the file by passing the file to the body of the call to fetch. 
However before upload I would like to compress the file. Since it is not feasible to keep the file in memory, i would like to compress and stream it to the server on the fly. 
Is it possible to pass some kind of stream to the fetch call to allow this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http
look at this one