# Plotting real-time graph from live JSON in webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, json, graph

I am creating a real-time javascript graph in my php web page. Below is the javascript graph called "Smoothie" and I have changed the "Math.random()" to my value which I have parsed the data from JSON URL. However, it is not updating in real-time. I have used the html  refesh for 5 seconds but it is resetting the graph.

```js
var smoothie = new SmoothieChart({
  grid: { strokeStyle:'rgb(125, 0, 0)', fillStyle:'rgb(60, 0, 0)',
          lineWidth: 1, millisPerLine: 250, verticalSections: 6, },
  labels: { fillStyle:'rgb(60, 0, 0)' }
});
smoothie.streamTo(document.getElementById("mycanvas"),1 /*delay*/);

// Data
var line1 = new TimeSeries();
var line2 = new TimeSeries();

// Add a random value to each line every second
var sw_2=<?php echo json_encode($sw2); ?>; //from JSON (live-data)
var sw_1=<?php echo json_encode($sw1); ?>; //from JSON (live-data)

setInterval(function() {
  line1.append(new Date().getTime(), 'sw_2'); //it was "Math.random()"
  line2.append(new Date().getTime(), 'sw_1');}, 1000);//tried change this delay,no luck

// Add to SmoothieChart
smoothie.addTimeSeries(line1,{ strokeStyle:'rgb(0, 255, 0)', fillStyle:'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4)', lineWidth:3 });
smoothie.addTimeSeries(line2,{ strokeStyle:'rgb(255, 0, 255)', fillStyle:'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3)', lineWidth:3 });
```

This is the input data, parsed from the JSON,

```
$json_string = '[![http://0.0.0.0:8080/wm/statistics/bandwidth/00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01/1/json][1]][1]';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$sw1=$obj[1]['bits-per-second-rx'];
$sw2=$obj[2]['bits-per-second-rx'];
```

As the JSON data are packets from the network and it is bits per second, it is updating every second in the JSON URL. The Json look like this [image]

However, I am unable to display update value in my java smoothie graph.

Found similar question:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558129/process-a-continuous-stream-of-json) but doesn't help me.

Here is another graph, I have tried another graph with the same concept [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0eb6mmdj/1/)

Comment: Your provided code runs on an error. Also check your JSFiddle, its not working. The question you linked shows the way to go! `file_get_contents()` only executes once - for your purpose you have to stream the json like in your linked question. html reload resets the complete site for sure :)

Comment: @FelixHäberle, unfortunately, the code will not work as u can see is running on localhost. The code are there and understand the concepts so u can point out mistake or errors.thx

Comment: ajax poll for new data, or websockets

Comment: @nogad, would you be able to explain and put example as in answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, working few weeks I have finally found out the technology called "Ajax" which can be used to update the information from the PHP page (there is the separate code for PHP). I have first created PHP page to grab the information then the js script will update information for every 1-second update.

```js
<script>
var graph5; // global
function requestData6() {
$.ajax({
url: 'graph/sw7port1.php', 
success: function(point) {var series = graph5.series[0],
shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
// add the point
graph5.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
// call it again after one second
setTimeout(requestData6, 1000);},
cache: false});}
$(document).ready(function() {
graph5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {renderTo: 'sw7_port1',defaultSeriesType: 'spline',events: {load: requestData6}},
title: {text: 'Switch 7 -Host 7'},
xAxis: {type: 'datetime',tickPixelInterval: 150,maxZoom: 20 * 1000},
yAxis: {minPadding: 0.2,maxPadding: 0.2,title: {text: 'bits-per-second-rx',margin: 40}},
series: [{name: 'Live Traffic Port1',data: []}]});});
</script>
```

```html
<?php
//header('Content-type: application/json');


Session_start(); //session store
//----------------------------Getting packets data rate from switch 1----variables-------------------//
$json_string = 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/wm/statistics/bandwidth/00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03/2/json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$sw0=$obj[0]['bits-per-second-rx'];
$sw1=$obj[1]['bits-per-second-rx'];
$sw2=$obj[2]['bits-per-second-rx'];
$sw3=$obj[3]['bits-per-second-rx'];
if ($_GET['run']) {
  exec("sh enable.sh");
}

$x1 = time() * 1000;
$y = rand(0, 100);



$ret1 = array($x1, $sw2);

echo str_replace('"', '', json_encode($ret1));


?>
```

Hopefully, this will help if someone is trying to figure out this thing as me.
Feel free to comment and ask me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
var graph5; // global
function requestData6() {
$.ajax({
url: 'graph/sw7port1.php', 
success: function(point) {var series = graph5.series[0],
shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
// add the point
graph5.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
// call it again after one second
setTimeout(requestData6, 1000);},
cache: false});}
$(document).ready(function() {
graph5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {renderTo: 'sw7_port1',defaultSeriesType: 'spline',events: {load: requestData6}},
title: {text: 'Switch 7 -Host 7'},
xAxis: {type: 'datetime',tickPixelInterval: 150,maxZoom: 20 * 1000},
yAxis: {minPadding: 0.2,maxPadding: 0.2,title: {text: 'bits-per-second-rx',margin: 40}},
series: [{name: 'Live Traffic Port1',data: []}]});});
</script>
```